# Deploy Symfony 4 application but composer has "cache:clear error"

Tags: symfony, deployment, symfony4

I try to deploy my Symfony application and when I use composer to install dependencies, I get an error.
I saw that there were people who had the same problem but I didn' t find a solution. Like change in `.env` `APP_ENV=dev` to `APP_ENV=prod`.

Here the logs :

```sh
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DoctrineFixturesBundle" from namespace "Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle".
!!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build.YZSXu7Ir2b/src/Kernel.php:23
```

I use **DoctrineFixturesBundle** only in dev environment :

```
"require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.1",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.8",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
    }
```

Here my **config/bundles.php** :

```php
...
 Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
...
```

And here Line 23 of **Kernel.php** :

```php
...
public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
                yield new $class(); // line 23
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your problem, you just have **Composer Install**, but the best is to do that **composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader** it's explained [**Here**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html). Otherwise, I do not know

Comment: Thanks, It works with `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader but I still had trouble understanding the behavior of `composer-install` between dev and production. I learn more with your documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if directory **"vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle"** exists and if there are files inside - specifically the "**vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle.php"**

If they are not there then it seems you didnt executed **"composer update"** to add the package. In such case please try:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

You should see something like:

```
- Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
- Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (3.2.2): Loading from cache
```

Comment: Thank you, I resolve my problem with `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`.
The vendor folder was created normally after this command.

Comment: Ok @Menthe-Pastille - please keep in mind that when you will add new package to composer.json you will need to run "composer update package-name-here" instead of "composer install". Please read this chapter: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies